# NodeJS: incorrect result of array.join

Tags: arrays, node.js

I noticed incorrect output of array.join with array of strings containing (\r) character. Here's my code and output:

```
var list = [
"one\r",
"two\r",
"three\r",
"four\r"]
console.log(list); // ok, output: [ 'one\r', 'two\r', 'three\r', 'four\r' ]
console.log(list.join(',')); // incorrect, outputs: ,foure
```

It works fine in chrome/firefox consoles, just not in nodejs.
I'm using node 6.11.3 on linux mint 18.3 if that matters

I can do workarounds for this, but I'm more interested in why this is happening.

Comment: `,foure` makes sense since a naked carriage return simply moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line (except in ancient Mac OSes) - so everything is overwritten by `,four` on the last go except the last `e` in `three`. My best guess is that browser implementations choose to interpret any combination of carriage return/line feed as a line break.

Comment: For example, at ``console.log(JSON.stringify(list.join(',')));``, ``"one\r,two\r,three\r,four\r"`` can be retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the string is joined successfully in your code, the output result ",foure" is caused by char '\r', which called "linefeed", line feed in Linux / macOS terminal moves the cursor to the beginning of a line, so:

- "one\r" outputs: "one"
- "one\r,two\r" outputs: "two"
- "one\r,two\r,three\r" outputs: "three"
- "one\r,two\r,three\r,four\r" outputs: "foure"

the last char "e" is from "three", `\r` is not "new line".
Use "\n" `Carriage Return` to output new line, and just put it in "join(',\n')" instead of putting it in elements of array.

```
var list = [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four"];
    console.log(list); // ok, output: [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ]
    console.log(list.join(',\n'));
```